# ERROR: The _Imputation value is not a valid SAS name

Tags: sas

I'm trying to run this code in SAS

```
proc mi data=Mono1 seed=1423741  nimpute=6 out=outex18;
    class Trt;
    monotone reg;
    mnar adjust( y1 / adjustobs=(Trt='0') parms(shift=shift_c)=parm1);
         adjust( y1 / adjustobs=(Trt='1') parms(shift=shift_t)=parm1);
   var Trt y0 y1;
run;
```

but I get the following error

`ERROR: The _Imputation value is not a valid SAS name.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.OUTMI was only partially opened and will not be saved.`

also mnar is in red.

How can I solve this problem?

the data is

```
data Mono1;
   input trt y0 y1;
   cards;
    0 10.5212 11.3604
    0 8.5871 8.5178
    0 9.3274 .
    0 9.7519 .
    0 9.3495 9.4369
    1 11.5192 13.2344
    1 10.7841 .
    1 9.7717 10.9407
    1 10.1455 10.8279
    1 8.2463 9.6844
   ;
run;
```

Comment: http://support.sas.com/kb/12/607.html

Comment: now I get this `ERROR 14-12: Invalid option value nimpute for SAS option VALIDVARNAME.`

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet I don't see that as a likely issue here unless there's more that OP hasn't shown, but who knows. Bubleskmy, please add the PARM1 table example also to the question (edit it). Thanks.

Comment: @bubleskmy It looks like you're working with an example from the documentation, but you've modified it some.  Could you clarify how you've modified it and why?  Likely a modification was made without considering impact on other things, and that's your problem.

Comment: Also - you have an extra semicolon after the first adjust statement, is that also present in your code or just in the transferral to here?

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

It appears that you example is from [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/131/mi.pdf). usually it helps when taking the whole bit from the example. There seems to be a typo in parameters file. This works with SAS 9.4:

```
    data Mono1;
       input Obs Trt y0 y1;
       cards;
    1 0 10.5212 11.3604
    2 0 8.5871 8.5178
    3 0 9.3274 .
    4 0 9.7519 .
    5 0 9.3495 9.4369
    6 1 11.5192 13.1344
    7 1 10.7841 .
    8 1 9.7717 10.8407
    9 1 10.1455 10.7279
    10 1 8.2463 9.5844
       ;
    run;

    data parm1; 
     input Obs _IMPUTATION_ SHIFT_C shift_t; 
     cards;
    1 1 -0.56986 -0.90494
    2 2 -0.38681 -0.84523
    3 3 -0.58342 -0.92793
    4 4 -0.48210 -0.99031
    5 5 -0.57188 -1.02095
    6 6 -0.57604 -1.008
    ;run;

    proc mi data=Mono1 seed=1423741 nimpute=6 out=outex18;
        class Trt;
        monotone reg;
        mnar adjust( y1 / adjustobs=(Trt='0') parms(shift=SHIFT_C)=parm1)
            adjust( y1 / adjustobs=(Trt='1') parms(shift=shift_t)=parm1);
        var Trt y0 y1;
    run;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I use the code `options validvarname=nimpute;`
but it comes out `ERROR 14-12: Invalid option value nimpute for SAS option VALIDVARNAME`

Comment: @bubleskmy I do not know what to say. The code works without errors when I copy-paste-execute what I've written.